# Details of VM and cluster

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a command t get the cluster details from list of VM'.

```
ForEach ($VM in Get-Content C:\Temp\servers.txt)
{
Get-Cluster (Get-VM $vm).ComputerName     
}
```

and the output of the script shows only cluster details of VM as below

```
Name
----
dhypervcl001
dhypervcl001
dhypervcl001
```

Can anyone tell me , how I can get an out put in below format i.e servername and clustername

```
server1, dhypervcl001
server2, dhypervcl0011
server3, dhypervcl012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `string.Format`:

```
ForEach ($VM in Get-Content C:\Temp\servers.txt)
{
"{0},{1}" -f $vm, (Get-Cluster (Get-VM $vm).ComputerName)     
}
```

Or `PSCustomObject`:

```
ForEach ($VM in Get-Content C:\Temp\servers.txt)
{
$Row = "" | Select Server,Cluster
$Row.Server = $VM
$Row.Cluster = (Get-Cluster (Get-VM $vm).ComputerName) 
$Row
}
```